# Inner private class and public method

Tags: java

If I have something like this:

```
public class Outer {

    private class Inner {
        public void someMethod() {}
    }

    Inner in = new Inner();
    in.someMethod(); //What??
}
```

Why doesn't last line code work?

Comment: good question,no reason why it should be downvoted!!

Comment: @KumarAbhinav It is probably downvoated because the OP did not say what "does not work" mean. Is there a compile error? A runtime error? An output that wasn't expected? If there is a stack trace, where is the stack trace? A question is not "good" when it seems to be interesting. It's good when it gives all the information required to understand the problem, replicate it, and work on an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why doesn't last line code work?

Because it has to be wrapped within a block ([initializer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html), [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html), [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)).

For example (wrapper within a constructor):

```
public class Outer {

    private class Inner {
        public void someMethod() {}
    }

    public Outer() {
        Inner in = new Inner();
        in.someMethod();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just cant invoke any method directly from class body. It has to be a method or constructor or initilizer block